# Proof that bilinear form in $H_0^1$ is coercive

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bilinear-form

Let $$B(u,v)=\int_I uv + \int_I u'v'$$ where $u,v\in H_0^1(I)$ for a given interval $I=[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$.

How can I prove that the bilinear form $B$ is coercive, i.e., that
$$B(u,u)\ge C\Vert u\Vert_{H_0^1(I)}^2\ \ ?
$$

Here, $\Vert u\Vert_{H_0^1(I)}:=\int_I u^2 +\int_I (u')^2$.
I have tried using that this norm is equivalent to $\Vert u\Vert_{L^2}+\Vert u'\Vert_{L^2}$.

Comment: Well, according to your definitions, $B(u,u)=\|u\|_{H_0^1(I)}$ and thus the desired inequality holds with $C=1$ (your norm $\Vert u\Vert_{H_0^1(I)}$ isn't only equivalent to $\Vert u\Vert_{L^2}+\Vert u'\Vert_{L^2}$; it's is exactly $\Vert u\Vert_{L^2}+\Vert u'\Vert_{L^2}$).

Comment: Taking $C=1$, the inequality becomes $$B(u,u)\ge B(u,u)^2$$ but this only holds if $0\le B(u,u) \le 1$.

Also, how do you show that both norms are exactly the same?

Comment: My comment above is wrong (there are missing squares). I've tried to clarify in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bilinear form is $B:H_0^1(I)\times H_0^1(I)\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$B(u,v)=\int_I uv + \int_I u'v'.$$
You want to prove that $B$ is coercive. In other words, you want to prove that there is $C>0$ such that
$$|B(u,u)|\geq C\|u\|_{H_0^1(I)}^2.\tag{1}$$
To do this, you have to specify what is the norm in $H_0^1(I)$ (I think that there is a typo in your post). Well, there are three usual possibilities:

$\displaystyle\|u\|_{H_0^1(I)}=\left(\int_Iu^2+\int_I(u')^2\right)^{1/2}$ which can be written as $\displaystyle\|u\|_{H_0^1(I)}=\sqrt{\|u\|_{L^2(I)}^2+\|u'\|_{L^2(I)}^2}$;

$\displaystyle\|u\|_{H_0^1(I)}=\left(\int_Iu^2\right)^{1/2}+\left(\int_I(u')^2\right)^{1/2}$ which can be written as $\displaystyle\|u\|_{H_0^1(I)}=\|u\|_{L^2(I)}+\|u'\|_{L^2(I)}$;

$\displaystyle\|u\|_{H_0^1(I)}=\int_I(u')^2$ which can be written as $\displaystyle\|u\|_{H_0^1(I)}=\|u'\|_{L^2(I)}$.

These three norms are all equivalents and thus you can use any of them to prove the desired inequality $(1)$.

Well, using the first possibility above, we have
$$B(u,u)=\int_I u^2 + \int_I (u')^2=\|u\|_{H_0^1(I)}^2$$
which imply $(1)$ with $C=1$ (and thus the the equivalence that you said is not needed).